# Why can $(0,0,3/5,0,0,0,4/5,0,0)$ be written as $\frac35|3\rangle+\frac45|7\rangle$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

**Context**. $\newcommand{\qr}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}$ A passage from a lecture by Scott Aaronson: "As an example, instead of writing out a vector like $$(0,0,3/5,0,0,0,4/5,0,0),$$ you can simply write $$\frac{3}{5}\qr{3} + \frac{4}{5}\qr{7},$$ omitting all of the 0 entries."

Source:
https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html

**Question**.  Where does the $\qr{3}$ and $\qr{7}$ come from?  I do understand the amplitudes $3/5$ and $4/5$, but I'm looking for help on understanding the $3$ and $7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector is a list of elements that represent the weights for the sum of some basis. This basis can in this case be the set $\{|1\rangle,|2\rangle,|3\rangle,|4\rangle,|5\rangle,|6\rangle,|7\rangle,|8\rangle,|9\rangle\}$.  The weights are zero for $\{|1\rangle,|2\rangle,|4\rangle,|5\rangle,|6\rangle,|8\rangle,|9\rangle\}$  and therefore the corresponding terms omitted in the summation.

Comment: $\newcommand{\qr}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}$ So, this means that the basis is (in "base 2") $\qr{0001}, \qr{0010}, \qr{0011} = \qr{3}, ..., \qr{0111} = \qr{7}, ..., \qr{1001}$?  (Thank you.  I get what you mean about the weights.)

Comment: Yes, assuming you adopt MSB first format.

Comment: @user1145880 take note many people (including me) start counting from $0$ instead of from $1$. Thus I would call Aaronson's vector $\frac{3}{5}|2\rangle + \frac{4}{5}|6\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSpinelli.  Your comment made a big difference here.  Thanks a lot.  (Also thanks to gIS for writing a better question.)